# CSS: 2 thicknesses - 1 Font

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I use the [Google Roboto Font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) on my website but I have a little implementation problem. Google allows us to adjust the font thickness before importing:

The import code for the font with a thickness of **700**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');
```

The import code for the font with a thickness of **300**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');
```

My problem is, that the usage in the CSS isn't depending on the two imports. That means it's always

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

and I have no choice which of the 2 imported fonts I want to use.

Comment: `font-weight` -----

Comment: didn't think about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CSS-side you have to apply these rules rispectively:

```
font: normal 300 16px 'Roboto', sans-serif; //thin font
font: normal 700 16px 'Roboto', sans-serif; //bolder font
```

Comment: Have you tried with this import: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" rel="stylesheet"> ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `font-weight: 300;` and `font-weight: 700;` in your CSS rules as desired

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the import to grab both weights:

`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700);`

Then use `font-weight: 300;` or `font-weight: 700;` where you appropriate.

A la

```
.someclass { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; }
.someclass strong { font-weight: 700; }
```